# Windows update error 80072EE2 connecting to WSUS

Tags: windows-7, windows, updates, wsus

We have a new HP Elitebook 8440p with Windows 7 Pro 64-bit we are deploying on our network. It can run Windows Updates just fine across the Internet; however, when I point it to get Windows Update via the internal WSUS server, it comes back with the **error code 80072EE2**.

The WSUS server itself appears to work for all other computers in the domain apart from this new model.

**What I've done and information:**

- Reinstalling Windows 7 Pro from scratch
- I've checked the registry for any vendor WSUS server pointers
- Not running any proxy to connect to the server
- Eliminated Firewall and any security software from the
  equation
- Tried with and without AV, as well as fresh build with no AD ever
  installed
- Tried with the firewall on and with it off
- Connected it directly to the network the WSUS server was on
- Checked it for any spyware/malware (just in case)
- Registered the following dlls:  oleaut32.dll,  jscript.dll, 
  vbscript.dll,  msxml.dll,  softpub.dll,  wintrust.dll,  initpki.dll,
  cryptdlg.dll
- Tried changing the MTU of the LAN card, and also rolled back the driver
  to an older version.
- Tried running MS Fixit (both the newer version as well as the older
  version that allows you to run it in aggressive mode).
- Tried installing the latest version of Windows update agent.
- Tried the following  Start > type cmd in start search > right click
  “run as administrator”.

> ```
> net stop wuauserv 
> cd %systemroot% 
> ren SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old 
> net start wuauserv
> net stop bits - The BITS service is not started (message)
> net start bits 
> net stop cryptsvc 
> cd %systemroot%\system32 
> ren catroot2 catroot2.old - 
> net start cryptsvc 
> regsvr32 Softpub.dll /s
> regsvr32 Wintrust.dll /s
> regsvr32 Initpki.dll /s 
> regsvr32 Mssip32.dll /s
> ```

- Restart the computer after the above commands
- I can see it make the connection through my network and I can see it
  come up on the WSUS server under computers, however it just never
  seems to actually get past that.

Also tried installing the windows 7 64bit server update readiness tool. 
Here is my Windowsupdate.log

```
2016-01-29 15:35:50:634
 916 b84
PT +++++++++++  PT: Synchronizing server updates  +++++++++++
2016-01-29 15:35:50:634
 916 b84
PT   + ServiceId = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}, Server URL = http://172.16.8.21:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx
2016-01-29 15:38:16:182
 916 b84
Misc WARNING: Send failed with hr = 80072ee2.
2016-01-29 15:38:16:182
 916 b84
Misc WARNING: SendRequest failed with hr = 80072ee2. Proxy List used: <(null)> Bypass List used : <(null)> Auth Schemes used : <>
2016-01-29 15:38:16:182
 916 b84
Misc FATAL: SOAP/WinHttp - SendRequest: SendRequestUsingProxy failed. error 0x80072ee2
2016-01-29 15:38:16:182
 916 b84
PT   + Last proxy send request failed with hr = 0x80072EE2, HTTP status code = 0
2016-01-29 15:38:16:182
 916 b84
PT   + Caller provided credentials = No
2016-01-29 15:38:16:182
 916 b84
PT   + Impersonate flags = 0
2016-01-29 15:38:16:182
 916 b84
PT   + Possible authorization schemes used = 
2016-01-29 15:38:16:182
 916 b84
PT WARNING: SyncUpdates failure, error = 0x80072EE2, soap client error = 5, soap error code = 0, HTTP status code = 200
2016-01-29 15:38:16:182
 916 b84
PT WARNING: PTError: 0x80072ee2
2016-01-29 15:38:16:182
 916 b84
PT WARNING: SyncUpdates_WithRecovery failed.: 0x80072ee2
2016-01-29 15:38:16:182
 916 b84
PT WARNING: Sync of Updates: 0x80072ee2
2016-01-29 15:38:16:182
 916 b84
PT WARNING: SyncServerUpdatesInternal failed: 0x80072ee2
2016-01-29 15:38:16:182
 916 b84
Agent   * WARNING: Failed to synchronize, error = 0x80072EE2
2016-01-29 15:38:16:182
 916 b84
Agent   * WARNING: Exit code = 0x80072EE2
2016-01-29 15:38:16:182
 916 b84
Agent *********
2016-01-29 15:38:16:182
 916 b84
Agent **  END  **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates]
2016-01-29 15:38:16:182
 916 b84
Agent *************
2016-01-29 15:38:16:182
 916 b84
Agent WARNING: WU client failed Searching for update with error 0x80072ee2
2016-01-29 15:38:16:213
 916 588
AU >>##  RESUMED  ## AU: Search for updates [CallId = {EDED43F9-1E65-4EE2-ABC6-8ECBD9F69190}]
2016-01-29 15:38:16:213
 916 588
AU   # WARNING: Search callback failed, result = 0x80072EE2
2016-01-29 15:38:16:213
 916 588
AU   # WARNING: Failed to find updates with error code 80072EE2
2016-01-29 15:38:16:213
 916 588
AU #########
2016-01-29 15:38:16:213
 916 588
AU ##  END  ##  AU: Search for updates [CallId = {EDED43F9-1E65-4EE2-ABC6-8ECBD9F69190}]
2016-01-29 15:38:16:213
 916 588
AU #############
```

Comment: Usually the laptops and computers are on a separate subnet, however they have routes through to the server and all the other computers have been connecting fine.                                                                  Yes though, we have tried connecting said laptop directly to the same network scope of that server and still the same error.                                     And also yes, have tried all the solutions from that article.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that already though. Same issue still.

Comment: I have also tried disabling Ipv6. Still the same error. All my other pc's connect to the current server without any issue.